# trying to render two different pages using two different entry points webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

My webpack is partitioned to produce two outputs...

```
entry: {
    a: './src',
    b: './Authentication'
},

devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path:'/',
    filename: 'scripts/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

So one of my html file (login.html) will call...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/a.entry.js'></script>
```

And the other (index.html) calls...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='./scripts/b.js'></script>
```

Now each of these pages is a different route. Obviously `index.html` will be the main so in my server I did...

```
var path = require('path');
...
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('public')));
...
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});
```

Everything renders find when I test it on local. But now I want to access the second `login.html` on a different route, I added this...

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/login.html'));
});
```

But when I go to `localhost:3000/login` I get this error...

```
GET http://localhost:3000/scripts/a.entry.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The output is not found. Why is this so???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configured your bundle for *login.html* to be named “a”, not “a.entry”. Try changing your script tag to:

```
<script src='scripts/a.js'></script>
```

(you don't need *type="text/javascript"* anymore in 2016)

Comment:  glad I could help